# Does anyone know if there is any UI to create and manage stuff in one Google Cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm very curious if there is a UI that allows a non dev user to manage content inside an instance of Google Cloud.

So instead of ssh-ing into a instance, there could be like a webportal where one could login with google and view stuff that is created in that instance?

Comment: The closest one i can think of is this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser. Give him/her minimum requirement to go there so that they can use SSH browser

Comment: There are many third-party tools that you can install to manage an instance remotely using a browser interface. Google search for one that meets your requirements. Review apps like cPanel and Webmin: https://www.tecmint.com/gui-tools-for-linux-system-administrators/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not a complete solution. I've found a github project that gives you an UI of your NGINX

https://github.com/schenkd/nginx-ui